# Alias or command to compile and link all C files

Tags: c, linux, bash, gcc

I recently started compiling/linking my C files by hand using the gcc command. However it requires all of the source files to be typed at the end of the command. When there are many files to compile/link it can be boring.
That's why I had the idea of making a bash alias for the command which would directly type all *.h and *.c files of the folder.

My line in .bashrc is this:

> alias compile='ls *.c *.h | gcc -o main'

I found it to work some times but most of the time compile will return this :

> gcc: fatal error: no input files
>
> compilation terminated.

I thought that pipe would give the results of ls *.c *.h as arguments to gcc but it doesn't seem to work that way. What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to achieve the same thing?

Thanks for helping

Comment: You really should take a look at `make` and `Makefile` in various incarnations over time.

Comment: E.g. this is a nice example for `make` which finds the sources automatically and compiles into a subdirectory: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14028369/416224

Comment: Better systems are grade or scons to name two

Answer (score 7):

A pipe does not create command line arguments. A pipe feeds standard input.

You need `xargs` to convert standard input to command line arguments.

But you don't need (or want) `xargs` or `ls` or standard input here at all.

If you just want to compile every `.c` file into your executable then just use:

```
gcc -o main *.c
```

(You don't generally need `.h` files on `gcc` command lines.)

As Kay points out in the comments the pedantically correct and safer version of the above command is (and I don't intend this in a pejorative fashion):

```
gcc -o main ./*.c
```

See [Filenames and Pathnames in Shell: How to do it Correctly](http://www.dwheeler.com/essays/filenames-in-shell.html) for an extensive discussion of the various issues here.

That being said you can use any of a number of tools to save you from needing to do this and from needing to rebuild everything when only some things change.

Tools like `make` or its many clones, "front-ends" (e.g. the autotools, cmake) or replacements (tup, scons, cons, and about a million other tools).

Comment: NEVER use `*.foo`, use `./*.foo` instead.

Comment: @Kay While true that's a level of pedantry even I haven't been convinced is generally worth it. It is, unarguably, more correct and safer in the face of all sorts of "bad" file names but in anything not intended for general usage on random input I've never been convinced that the cost is worth the retraining.

Comment: @EtanReisner there will be seldom ever a need to use shell globbing without a relative (or absolute) path. That's why I'd use `./*glob*` in answers, not to teach a bad habit. As an argument for `gcc` it does not really matter I guess, but once $USER wants to implement `clean` in their bash script ...

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried using a [makefile](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Introduction)?  It sounds like that might be more efficient for what you're trying to do.

If you really want to do it with BASH aliases, you have to use xargs to get standard input to command line arguments.

Comment: You might improve your answer with a sample Makefile

Answer (score 4):

There are several misconceptions here:

- the pipe redirects the standard output of the first command to the standard input of the second command; however, gcc doesn't accept the files to compile on stdin, but on the command line;
- the wildcard syntax is not something that is magical just to `ls`, it's the shell that performs their expansion on the command line;
- header files are *not* to be compiled - you compile `.c` files, which in turn may include headers.

Armed with this knowledge, you'll understand that the correct command  something like

```
gcc -o main *.c
```

Actually we can do better: first of all, you'll want to change the `*.c` to `./*.c`; this prevents files whose name start with a `-` from being interpreted as command line options.

Most importantly, you should really enable the compiler warnings, they can be life saver. You'll want to add `-Wall` and `-Wextra`.

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -o main ./*.c
```

Finally, it's worth saying that by default you are compiling with optimizations disabled. If you are debugging that's OK, but you want also to add `-g` to have an executable usable in debugging; otherwise, if the target is speed you should at least add `-O2`.

Comment: The standard way to prevent files with names starting with `-` from being seen as input files is to add a `--` operand right after the last option.

Comment: @FUZxxl: that's supported by many commands (including gcc) but it's not universal. Also, it's not possible to use it for arguments other than the last one.

Comment: `--` is part of POSIX and all applications that use `getopt()` for parsing or that follow the [UCB utility conventions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) should obey it. What do you mean with “arguments other than the last one?” A command's arguments are always first options and then operands except with GNU utilities, these don't follow the standard for god knows what stupid reason. Notice further that `-llibrary` is an operand, not an option to `cc`.

Comment: @FUZxxl, there are actually people and programs who don't follow conventions, hard to believe but it's true. ;) Actually I just used [qpdf](http://qpdf.sourceforge.net/) which does not understand `--`.

Comment: @FUZxxl: what Kay said. Life is too short to learn about UCB and who does abide to it, who says to do so but actually fails to comply in some cases and to take a definite position in the multifaceted debate about the pros and cons of each and every standard of command line options and its nuances of purity. Honestly, I don't give a damn; I just want to avoid bizarre stuff in case someone puts a `-rf` file where my scripts are going to operate, and I prefer to learn once the safer globbing syntax rather than remembering all the exceptions for the various commands.